# C++ templated class self-inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

I've got this code:

```
template<typename A, typename B = A>
class MyClass;

template<typename A>
class MyClass<A, void>
{
protected:
    A a;

    MyClass<A, void>(const A& a):
        a(a)
    {}
public:
    const A& getA() const
    {
        return a;
    }
};

template<typename A, typename B>
class MyClass : public MyClass<A, void>
{
private:
    B b;
public:
    MyClass<A, B>(const A& a, const B& b):
        MyClass<A, void>(a), b(b)
    {}

    const B& getB() const
    {
        return b;
    }

    const auto getAplusB() const
    {
        return a+b;
    }
};
```

`getAplusB` method fails to compile with message `a is not declared`. However, inheritance seems to work, so I can use `this->getA() + b`. I've also tried to do `dynamic_cast<const MyClass<A, void>*>(this)->a + b`, but got another compilation error `a is protected`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Apparently, changing `a` to `this->a` works...

Comment: @user202729 good point. It solves my issue, but I still waiting for someone who can explain this.

Comment: Already in the answer below.

Comment: Yes, I see now, it was not here when I refreshed the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to simply use `this->a` or a *qualified name* `MyClass<A, void>::a`. This is because `a` is member of a base *class-template*. There is such a thing known as [name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) - When the compiler sees a [*name*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/name), it does the said [*name lookup*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup).

Simply trying to make unqualified accesses `a` will not work because it's a [*dependent name*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) (by meaning of it depending on the *instantiation* of some template somewhere). Hence you have to qualify the accesses to `a`

Comment: You can also just say, under the `private` or `protected` section, `using MyClass<A, void>::a;` and then use it as normal.